# REST Post Call from ASP.NET Hangs

Tags: asp.net, rest

I am working on a simple post call to the USAePay REST API within an ASP.NET project. Their SDK (v.2.1.6) has both the Post and PostAsync methods. Using the Post method, my code hangs at the call below. I know the call works, the request submitted appears in the sandbox portal. The question is why doesn't the code progress past this point? I have read about deadlocks when using Async, but from what I can tell that is not the issue here. Also please note, I know enough to be dangerous. I am by no means a seasoned developer.

response = USAePay.API.Customers.Post(request)

I have attempted to use both Post and PostAsync methods. I was unsuccessful in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. Way down the stack the SDK used an async method. I ended up converting to async.